# PHP Namespace, Do Directories Matter?

Tags: php, namespaces

Suppose you are trying to extend a class that's in a totally different directory and that also has a namespace. Can you simply use that namespace to get at the class, or do you need to include it with the correct directory path? Does PHP automatically know where the file is when using a namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple terms, namespaces are ways of naming resources in a way to avoid comflicts, so yes you can extend a namespace based on another. However, you must still include the file for PHP to use it. Namespacing does not necessarily automatically include files for you. Namespacing and a registered autoloader will do that for you.